# A question on 't Hooft's paper "Computation of the quantum effects due to a four-dimensional pseudo-particle"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, instantons

In the avove paper 't Hooft considers the following (rotation invarinat) operators on the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^4$:

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{M}_0=-\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)^2-\frac{3}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}-\frac{1}{2r^2}(x_\mu\partial_\nu-x_\nu\partial_\mu)^2,\\
\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{M}_0+\delta\mathcal{M}, 
\end{eqnarray}
where $\delta\mathcal{M}$ is the first order differential operator which commutes with $SO(4)$-rotations and involves some spin and isospin operators (let me omit the explicit form of it since I am not sure it is relevant).

> If I understand correctly, on p. 3436, Section III, 3 lines right before formula (3.1), 't Hooft essentially claims that $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{M}_0$ have the same spectrum if we remove 0 from both of them.  Why this should be true?

**Remark.** This seems to be similar to some results in scattering theory where one shows that under some assumptions $\Delta$ and $\Delta+V$ have the same continuous spectrum, where $V$ is a potential which decays sufficiently fast.

Comment: I'm confused about this section of the paper too, but I think you misunderstood that paragraph. In the second paragraph of section III., 't Hooft is simply saying that there are zero eigenvalues of $\mathfrak{M}_0$, and  even more zero eigenvalues of $\mathfrak{M}$ in the limit $R\rightarrow \infty$. These zero eigenvalues must be excluded from the calculation of $\det\mathfrak{M}/\det\mathfrak{M}_0=\prod_n E(n)/E_0(n)$.